# Text inside container over a full-width two-col background on Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to implement a section from a mockup with Bootstrap 4 that features a full-width two-column background, 50% of it is filled by an image. On the other half of the page, there is text within a container with the same margins than the rest of the webpage. Here is a look about what I'm trying to do.

[image: Mockup]

I've tried to nest a container within a 2-col container-fluid, but it's not applying the margins of the container on the text. I know already nesting containers is not advisable, so any suggestions on getting this in a better way would be welcome.

Here is the code I got so far.

```css
.salespitch {
  height: auto;
  background-color: #F6F7F9;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="salespitch">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
            </div>
            <div class="pitchText">
              <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h2>
              <p>Text.</p>
              <p>Moar text.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: show your css, pls

Comment: Added. However it's a simple one, the rest of them are vanilla-BS or aren't defined yet on the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```css
.left {
  padding-left: 5rem !important; /* Or other value */
}
.right {
  padding-right: 5rem !important; /* Or other value */
}

.salespitch {
  height: auto;
  background-color: #F6F7F9;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="salespitch">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 left">
        <div class="pitchText">
          <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h2>
          <p>Text.</p>
          <p>Moar text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 right">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I think the image should reach the far end right whatever the resolution is on desktop. This example doesn't work